# how to store 100+ questions data in android game using sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am developing a Quiz game. I know about sqlite database creation and the use of DBhandler etc.. but, the problem is that I could not find how to **create a database file in assets folder** in my android project.
Kindly help me.
                   Thanks in advance

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems you'd like a "static" sqlite db. Perhaps you'd be better off creating the db on your Dev machine (the one building apks) and put it in your assets folder, for reference by the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that i got it now. In order to store any type of data we have to create the db file that can be created by any sqlite database browser like **[this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)**

After creating the db, import it in the assets folder of android project and use following commands to access it:

```
 //The Android's default system path of the application's database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.brainstorm/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "Brainstorm.db";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

private final Context myContext;


 /* Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 * @param context
 */
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}   

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }
    else{

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
           //of your application so we are going to be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.
        Log.e("DBHelper", "DataBase Does Not Exist closing returning null");

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        Log.e("DBHelper", "DataBase Exists closing checkDB");
        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transferring byte-stream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [SQliteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) by Jeff Gilfelt.
The GitHub homepage for SQLiteAssetHelper has well documented Setup and Usage information.